# Prisma throws an error "TypeError: cannot read property findmany of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I wanted to make a chat app to practice working with graphql and node, for database I used prisma. I was doing everything like in this tutorial.

https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/0-introduction/

I just changed variable names.

so I have this code

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')
const prisma = new PrismaClient()


const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    history: async (parent, args, context) => {
      return context.prisma.Messages.findMany()
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    post: (parent, args, context) => {
      const newMessage = context.prisma.Messages.create({
        data: {
          username: args.username,
          message: args.message,
        },
      })
      return newMessage
    },
  },
}

const server = new GraphQLServer({
  typeDefs: './src/schema.graphql',
  resolvers,
  context: {
    prisma,
  }
})
server.start(() => console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:4000`))
```

as my index.js

this is my schema.prisma

```
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = "file:./dev.db"
}


generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}


model Message {
  id       Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  sendedAt DateTime @default(now())
  message  String
  username String
}
```

script.js

```
const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client")


const prisma = new PrismaClient()


async function main() {
  const newMessage = await prisma.Messages.create({
    data: {
      message: 'Fullstack tutorial for GraphQL',
      username: 'www.howtographql.com',
    },
  })
  const allMessages = await prisma.Messages.findMany()
  console.log(allMessages)
}


main()
  .catch(e => {
    throw e
  })
  // 5
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.disconnect()
  })
```

and schema.graphql

```
type Query {
  history: [Message!]!
}

type Mutation {
  post(username: String!, message: String!): Message!
}

type Message {
  id: ID!
  message: String!
  username: String!
}
```

and that is what i got in my playground

```
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read property 'findMany' of undefined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "history"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

please help

Answer (score 8):

It should be noted it is not actually lowercase but **camel case**.

**Example**:

Model name: `Message` -> Prisma client name: `message`

Model name: `MessagePerUser` -> Prisma client name: `messagePerUser`

Answer (score 4):

I managed to fix that. Actually, all I needed was to use the same name but lowercased as in schema.prisma

Comment: The same name for what – can you elaborate what exactly was the error?

Answer (score 1):

Would like to add on to the answer

Basically when calling await **prisma.User.create**, prisma allows the User model to be in caps, but when calling other models such as **prisma.messages.create** the m has to be in lowercase. Essentially,for all prisma calls, the models should be in **lowercase**. Hopefully this answers your question, prisma does not flag this error out

Answer (score 0):

use Table name as camelCase in prisma Client to make Queries

Example:
Table Name is: `StudentData`

then use camelCase according to table name
prisma.`studentData`.findMany();

Answer (score 0):

const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

so this in an imp part i resolved my issue just by doing this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.